# Adding elements to python generators

Tags: python, append, generator

Is it possible to append elements to a python generator?

I'm currently trying to get all images from a set of disorganized folders and write them to a new directory. To get the files, I'm using os.walk() which returns a list of image files in a single directory. While I can make a generator out of this single list, I don't know how to combine all these lists into one single generator. Any help would be much appreciated.

Related:

- [Flattening a shallow list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should do it, where `directories` is your list of directories:

```
import os
import itertools

generators = [os.walk(d) for d in directories]
for root, dirs, files in itertools.chain(*generators):
    print root, dirs, files
```

Comment: `chain.from_iterable(imap(os.walk, directories))`

Answer (score 34):

You are looking for [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). It will combine multiple iterables into a single one, like this:

```
>>> import itertools 
>>> for i in itertools.chain([1,2,3], [4,5,6]):
...     print(i)
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: How do you use `chain` in the context of `os.walk`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: `chain(os.walk("."), other_generator)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
def files_gen(topdir='.'):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):
        # ... do some stuff with files
        for f in files:
            yield os.path.join(root, f)
        # ... do other stuff

for f in files_gen():
    print f
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this.

```
def threeGens( i, j, k ):
    for x in range(i):
       yield x
    for x in range(j):
       yield x
    for x in range(k):
       yield x
```

Works well.

Comment: `itertools.chain(range(i), range(j), range(k))`

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Not when the range is os.walk(...).